# Capture Sound from microphone using Directx DirectSound

Tags: c#, .net, directx, directsound

I am creating a simple application that records input from the microphone and store it into array of bytes. So I have searched a lot about this and eventually ended up using Directx DirectSound. Here is the code I am using:

```
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;

private Thread CaptureSoundThread = null;
public CaptureBuffer applicationBuffer = null;
private SecondaryBuffer soundBuffer = null;
private Device soundDevice = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    soundDevice = new Device();
    soundDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(this, CooperativeLevel.Normal);

    // Set up our wave format to 44,100Hz, with 16 bit resolution
    WaveFormat wf = new WaveFormat();
    wf.FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm;
    wf.SamplesPerSecond = 44100;
    wf.BitsPerSample = 16;
    wf.Channels = 1;
    wf.BlockAlign = (short)(wf.Channels * wf.BitsPerSample / 8);
    wf.AverageBytesPerSecond = wf.SamplesPerSecond * wf.BlockAlign;

    int samplesPerUpdate = 512;

    // Create a buffer with 2 seconds of sample data
    BufferDescription bufferDesc = new BufferDescription(wf);
    bufferDesc.BufferBytes = samplesPerUpdate * wf.BlockAlign * 2;
    bufferDesc.ControlPositionNotify = true;
    bufferDesc.GlobalFocus = true;

    soundBuffer = new SecondaryBuffer(bufferDesc, soundDevice);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CaptureSoundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WaitThread));
    CaptureSoundThread.Start();
}

private void WaitThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] CaptureData = null;
        CaptureData = (byte[])applicationBuffer.Read(0,
        typeof(byte), LockFlag.None);
        soundBuffer.Write(0, CaptureData, LockFlag.None);
        // Start it playing
        soundBuffer.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Looping);
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the application, I get this annoying error:

```
BadImageFormatException

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll' or one
of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
```

I actually had to download the Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll from the internet because I couldn't find them in the Visual Studio assemblies.

EDIT : I JUST SOLVED THAT by reading this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383138/BadImageFormatException-x86-i-x64

Comment: You might want to answer your own question if your problem is solved.  That way, if anyone runs into the same problem, your answer shows up following the same convention.